Monaco Editor Custom Language Autocompletion Not Triggering (Tokenizer Issue? Syntax Highlighting Mostly Works)
I'm creating a custom language for Monaco Editor and having trouble with autocompletion. The provideCompletionItems function in my completion provider doesn't seem to be called at all. I've registered the language and the provider, but nothing happens when I type. I suspect there might be an issue with my tokenizer.
Interestingly, syntax highlighting is working for keywords, types, constants, and operators, but not for built-in functions.
Here's my language definition (CodeFrLanguage.js):
   import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';

// Language Definition (CodeFrLanguage.js - Minimal)
const keywords = ['Algorithme', 'Debut', 'Fin', 'Variable'];
const builtins = ['Racine', 'Abs']; // Built-in functions
const typeKeywords = ['Entier', 'Chaine'];

export const codeFrLanguage = {
    ignoreCase: false,
    defaultToken: '',
    tokenPostfix: '.codefr',

    keywords,
    typeKeywords,
    builtins,

    tokenizer: {
        root: [
            [/[a-zA-Z_]\w*/, {
                cases: {
                    '@keywords': 'keyword',
                    '@typeKeywords': 'type',
                    '@builtins': 'function', // Highlight built-ins
                    '@default': 'identifier'
                }
            }],
            [/[\s]+/, 'white'],
        ]
    }
};

export const codeFrConfig = {
    comments: {
      lineComment: '//',
      blockComment: ['/*', '*/']
    },
};

export const registerCodeFrLanguage = (monaco) => {
    monaco.languages.register({ id: 'codefr' });
    monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('codefr', codeFrLanguage);
    monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration('codefr', codeFrConfig);

    monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('codefr', {
        triggerCharacters: [' ', '\n', ':', '.', '(', '[', 'A', 'S', 'V'], // Trigger on a few letters
        provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
            console.log("Completion provider called!", position);
            const word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
            const range = {
                startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                startColumn: word.startColumn,
                endColumn: word.endColumn
            };
            const suggestions = builtins.map(builtin => ({
                label: builtin,
                kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
                insertText: builtin,
                range: range
            }));
            return { suggestions };
        }
    });
};

And here's how I'm creating the editor in my React component (MonacoEditor.js):
   import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const MonacoEditor = () => {
    const editorRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (editorRef.current) {
          import('monaco-editor').then(monaco => {
            if (!monaco.languages.getLanguages().some(({ id }) => id === 'codefr')) {
              registerCodeFrLanguage(monaco);
            }
            monaco.editor.create(editorRef.current, {
                value: 'Algorithme test\nDebut\nRacine\nAbs\nVariable test:Entier\nFin',
                language: 'codefr',
                theme: 'vs-dark',
                automaticLayout: true
            });
          });
        }
    }, []);

    return <div ref={editorRef} style={{ width: '800px', height: '600px' }}></div>;
};

export default MonacoEditor;

I've tried setting triggerCharacters to all letters and even added console.log statements inside provideCompletionItems, but they're never executed. I've also checked the console for errors and verified that the language is being registered.
Any help in diagnosing why the completion provider isn't being triggered and why built-in functions aren't highlighted would be greatly appreciated.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@AdamBasha I've trimmed the code. Thanks for your help
